# Weather data from NOAA API returning error from server

Tags: python, dataframe, api, url, noaa

I have run this code a few times, with the goal of returning NOAA data from weather stations listed. The code has worked previously, except today it is returning the error below. I'm not sure why considering the code hasn't changed, can anyone help me create a workaround? I am using a jupyter notebook.

````
d = "https://www.ncei.noaa.gov/access/services/data/v1?dataset=daily-summaries&dataTypes=PRCP,SNOW,TMAX,TMIN&stations=USW00026492,USW00024037,USW00014916,USW00014913,USW00094847,USW00014607,USW00054773,USW00014742,USW00094700,USW00014820,USW00014860,USW00023199,USW00023188,USW00023050,USW00003125,USW00023160,USW00022004,USW00022010,USW00012907,USW00012912,USW00012923,USW00012924,USW00012916,USW00012839,USW00012842,USW00022521,RQW00011630,USW00013743&startDate=2020-02-01&endDate=2020-02-01&includeAttributes=0&includeStationName=true&units=standard&format=json" #request from NOAA API
df_d = pd.read_json(d)
df = df_d.fillna(0) #replaces NaN values with 0

df.insert(3, "Lat", [60.785, 46.427, 47.943, 46.837, 42.231, 46.871, 43.35, 44.468, 44.576, 41.406, 42.08, 32.817, 32.734, 35.042, 32.833, 32.131, 29.378, 27.533, 28.783, 29.273, 27.774, 29.997, 25.791, 27.962, 21.324, 18.255, 38.847], True)
df.insert(4, "Lon", [-148.839,-105.883, -97.184, -92.183, -83.331, -68.017, -76.385, -73.15, -71.179, -81.852, -80.182, -115.683, -117.183, -106.616, -114.4, -110.955, -100.927, -99.467, -97.083, -94.859, -97.512, -90.278, -80.316, -82.54, -157.929, -65.641, -77.035], True)

df```

```
ConnectionResetError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
~\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py in do_open(self, http_class, req, **http_conn_args)
   1353             try:
-> 1354                 h.request(req.get_method(), req.selector, req.data, headers,
   1355                           encode_chunked=req.has_header('Transfer-encoding'))

~\Anaconda3\lib\http\client.py in request(self, method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
   1254         """Send a complete request to the server."""
-> 1255         self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
   1256 

~\Anaconda3\lib\http\client.py in _send_request(self, method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
   1300             body = _encode(body, 'body')
-> 1301         self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
   1302 

~\Anaconda3\lib\http\client.py in endheaders(self, message_body, encode_chunked)
   1249             raise CannotSendHeader()
-> 1250         self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
   1251 

~\Anaconda3\lib\http\client.py in _send_output(self, message_body, encode_chunked)
   1009         del self._buffer[:]
-> 1010         self.send(msg)
   1011 

~\Anaconda3\lib\http\client.py in send(self, data)
    949             if self.auto_open:
--> 950                 self.connect()
    951             else:

~\Anaconda3\lib\http\client.py in connect(self)
   1423 
-> 1424             self.sock = self._context.wrap_socket(self.sock,
   1425                                                   server_hostname=server_hostname)

~\Anaconda3\lib\ssl.py in wrap_socket(self, sock, server_side, do_handshake_on_connect, suppress_ragged_eofs, server_hostname, session)
    499         # ctx._wrap_socket()
--> 500         return self.sslsocket_class._create(
    501             sock=sock,

~\Anaconda3\lib\ssl.py in _create(cls, sock, server_side, do_handshake_on_connect, suppress_ragged_eofs, server_hostname, context, session)
   1039                         raise ValueError("do_handshake_on_connect should not be specified for non-blocking sockets")
-> 1040                     self.do_handshake()
   1041             except (OSError, ValueError):

~\Anaconda3\lib\ssl.py in do_handshake(self, block)
   1308                 self.settimeout(None)
-> 1309             self._sslobj.do_handshake()
   1310         finally:

ConnectionResetError: [WinError 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

URLError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-75e4cdb60933> in <module>
      1 d = "https://www.ncei.noaa.gov/access/services/data/v1?dataset=daily-summaries&dataTypes=PRCP,SNOW,TMAX,TMIN&stations=USW00026492,USW00024037,USW00014916,USW00014913,USW00094847,USW00014607,USW00054773,USW00014742,USW00094700,USW00014820,USW00014860,USW00023199,USW00023188,USW00023050,USW00003125,USW00023160,USW00022004,USW00022010,USW00012907,USW00012912,USW00012923,USW00012924,USW00012916,USW00012839,USW00012842,USW00022521,RQW00011630,USW00013743&startDate=2020-02-01&endDate=2020-02-01&includeAttributes=0&includeStationName=true&units=standard&format=json" #request from NOAA API
----> 2 df_d = pd.read_json(d)
      3 df = df_d.fillna(0) #replaces NaN values with 0
      4 
      5 df.insert(3, "Lat", [60.785, 46.427, 47.943, 46.837, 42.231, 46.871, 43.35, 44.468, 44.576, 41.406, 42.08, 32.817, 32.734, 35.042, 32.833, 32.131, 29.378, 27.533, 28.783, 29.273, 27.774, 29.997, 25.791, 27.962, 21.324, 18.255, 38.847], True)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\util\_decorators.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    197                 else:
    198                     kwargs[new_arg_name] = new_arg_value
--> 199             return func(*args, **kwargs)
    200 
    201         return cast(F, wrapper)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\util\_decorators.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    297                 )
    298                 warnings.warn(msg, FutureWarning, stacklevel=stacklevel)
--> 299             return func(*args, **kwargs)
    300 
    301         return wrapper

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\json\_json.py in read_json(path_or_buf, orient, typ, dtype, convert_axes, convert_dates, keep_default_dates, numpy, precise_float, date_unit, encoding, lines, chunksize, compression, nrows, storage_options)
    538         convert_axes = True
    539 
--> 540     json_reader = JsonReader(
    541         path_or_buf,
    542         orient=orient,

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\json\_json.py in __init__(self, filepath_or_buffer, orient, typ, dtype, convert_axes, convert_dates, keep_default_dates, numpy, precise_float, date_unit, encoding, lines, chunksize, compression, nrows, storage_options)
    620                 raise ValueError("nrows can only be passed if lines=True")
    621 
--> 622         data = self._get_data_from_filepath(filepath_or_buffer)
    623         self.data = self._preprocess_data(data)
    624 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\json\_json.py in _get_data_from_filepath(self, filepath_or_buffer)
    657             or file_exists(filepath_or_buffer)
    658         ):
--> 659             self.handles = get_handle(
    660                 filepath_or_buffer,
    661                 "r",

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\common.py in get_handle(path_or_buf, mode, encoding, compression, memory_map, is_text, errors, storage_options)
    556 
    557     # open URLs
--> 558     ioargs = _get_filepath_or_buffer(
    559         path_or_buf,
    560         encoding=encoding,

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\common.py in _get_filepath_or_buffer(filepath_or_buffer, encoding, compression, mode, storage_options)
    287                 "storage_options passed with file object or non-fsspec file path"
    288             )
--> 289         req = urlopen(filepath_or_buffer)
    290         content_encoding = req.headers.get("Content-Encoding", None)
    291         if content_encoding == "gzip":

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\common.py in urlopen(*args, **kwargs)
    193     import urllib.request
    194 
--> 195     return urllib.request.urlopen(*args, **kwargs)
    196 
    197 

~\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py in urlopen(url, data, timeout, cafile, capath, cadefault, context)
    220     else:
    221         opener = _opener
--> 222     return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
    223 
    224 def install_opener(opener):

~\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py in open(self, fullurl, data, timeout)
    523 
    524         sys.audit('urllib.Request', req.full_url, req.data, req.headers, req.get_method())
--> 525         response = self._open(req, data)
    526 
    527         # post-process response

~\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py in _open(self, req, data)
    540 
    541         protocol = req.type
--> 542         result = self._call_chain(self.handle_open, protocol, protocol +
    543                                   '_open', req)
    544         if result:

~\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py in _call_chain(self, chain, kind, meth_name, *args)
    500         for handler in handlers:
    501             func = getattr(handler, meth_name)
--> 502             result = func(*args)
    503             if result is not None:
    504                 return result

~\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py in https_open(self, req)
   1395 
   1396         def https_open(self, req):
-> 1397             return self.do_open(http.client.HTTPSConnection, req,
   1398                 context=self._context, check_hostname=self._check_hostname)
   1399 

~\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py in do_open(self, http_class, req, **http_conn_args)
   1355                           encode_chunked=req.has_header('Transfer-encoding'))
   1356             except OSError as err: # timeout error
-> 1357                 raise URLError(err)
   1358             r = h.getresponse()
   1359         except:

URLError: <urlopen error [WinError 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host>
```
````